# Check if a value has duplicate and the other column is different in a multidimensional array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I have multidimensional array like this.

```
array:8 [
  0 => array:8 [
    "SERIAL" => "qwerty"
    "BRANCH" => "TEST1"
  ]
  1 => array:8 [
    "SERIAL" => "qwer"
    "BRANCH" => "TEST1"
  ]
  2 => array:8 [   // RETURN THIS AS ERROR AS THE BRANCH "TEST1" has already "qwerty" serial
    "SERIAL" => "qwerty"
    "BRANCH" => "TEST2"
  ]
  3 => array:8 [   
    "SERIAL" => "qwerty"
    "BRANCH" => "TEST1"
  ]
]
```

My goal is to return error if there is a duplicate value of "SERIAL" and different "BRANCH".

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? A simple loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you group the serials and branches then you can see if the unique count is more than one.
This will output all the duplicates not just the first.

```
foreach($arr as $sub){
    $result[$sub['SERIAL']][] = $sub['BRANCH'];
}

foreach($result as $serial => $branches){
    $unique = array_unique($branches);
    if(count($unique) >1){
        var_dump("ERROR: " . $serial, array_slice($unique,1));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
string(13) "ERROR: qwerty"
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "TEST2"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "TEST3" // I added that to test on multiple duplicates
}
```

https://3v4l.org/Qj98N

Answer (score 1):

One option could be using 2 foreach loops and check if SERIAL is the same and BRANCH is different.

If that is the case, break out of the loops or handle it accordingly.

```
foreach ($arrays as $arrayA) {
    foreach ($arrays as $arrayB) {
        if ($arrayA["SERIAL"] == $arrayB["SERIAL"] && $arrayA["BRANCH"] !== $arrayB["BRANCH"]) {
            print_r($arrayB);
            break 2;
        }
    }
}
```

See a [php demo](https://3v4l.org/CAbaW)

Answer (score 1):

You could sort the array (here a copy) by SERIAL, and then if you have the same SERIAL values, check to see if they lie on different BRANCHs.

```
<?php
$dupes = false;
usort($result = $data, function($a, $b) use (&$dupes) {
    $out = $a['SERIAL'] <=> $b['SERIAL'];
    if($out === 0 && $a['BRANCH'] !== $b['BRANCH'])
        $dupes = true;

    return $out;
});

var_dump($dupes);
```

Output:

```
bool(true)
```